# How to get the sibling of every selector using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Assuming i have the following HTML:

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="sibling">content...</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="sibling">different content...</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="sibling">different content...</div>
</div>
```

How to set every child height as it's sibling content height?

```
$('.child').css('height', '... next sibling height ...');
```

Comment: Perhaps you could combine jQuery's [next](https://api.jquery.com/next/) and [outerHeight](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/) methods to do this?

Comment: This could be solved with CSS only using `grid` or `flex`. Or are you specifically looking for a JS/jQuery solution?

Comment: I was also going to suggest that this could be solved with flex, depending on your layout - the flex property `align-items` defaults to the value `stretch` - this basically takes all items in the flex container (if the flex container is `div.parent`, then the items inside would be `div.child` and `div.sibling`) and stretches them to the tallest height (which could be determined by the sibling content), and that sounds like it achieves your objective. And if possible, better to let CSS do the work instead of JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) and set style to current element (`this`) by [`.next`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) DOM's height

```js
$('.child').each(function() {
  $(this).css('height',$(this).next().height());
});
```

```css
.sibling{
height:15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="sibling">content...</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="sibling">different content...</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="sibling" style="height:55px;">different content...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: tell me for more help

Answer (score 0):

Note:- [siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) is used to get the **siblings** of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector

```js
$('.child').each(function() {
  $(this).siblings().css({"background-color": "red", "height": "20px"});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">content...</div>
  <div class="sibling">content...</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">content...</div>
  <div class="sibling">different content...</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">content...</div>
  <div class="sibling">different content...</div>
</div>
```